# JDBC Spring Integration with Annotations

Tags: cron, annotations, spring-integration, spring-jdbc

I am looking an example with annotated classes, completely XML free of this:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="select * from item where status=2"
channel="target" data-source="dataSource"
update="update item set status=10 where id in (:id)" />
```

OR

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter query="..."
    channel="target" data-source="dataSource" update="...">
<int:poller fixed-rate="1000">
    <int:transactional/>
</int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Maybe there exists a better solution such as Input messaging gateway for creating an entry point by querying a database with a CRON statement.
Cron Programmed query -> first channel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java & Annotation configuration variant:

```
@Bean
public PollerMetadata poller(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    PeriodicTrigger trigger = new PeriodicTrigger(1000);
    trigger.setFixedRate(true);

    MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource attributeSource = new MatchAlwaysTransactionAttributeSource();
    attributeSource.setTransactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute());
    TransactionInterceptor interceptor = new TransactionInterceptor(transactionManager, attributeSource);

    PollerMetadata poller = new PollerMetadata();
    poller.setTrigger(trigger);
    poller.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList(interceptor));
    return poller;
}

@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "target", poller = @Poller("poller"))
public MessageSource<?> counterMessageSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter =
            new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, "select * from item where status = 2");
    adapter.setUpdateSql("update item set status = 10 where id in (:id)");
    return adapter;
}
```

Right, the transaction configuration looks ugly, but there is not yet a simple way to provide a TX `Advice` to the `PollerMetadata`.

You can consider to use [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) on the matter:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource<?> jdbcAdapter(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter =
            new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(dataSource, "select * from item where status = 2");
    adapter.setUpdateSql("update item set status = 10 where id in (:id)");
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jdbcFlow(MessageSource<?> jdbcAdapter) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(jdbcAdapter, e ->
                    e.poller(p -> p.fixedRate(1000).transactional(transactionManager())))
            .channel(c -> c.direct("target"))
            .get();
}
```

Feel free to raise a GH-issue against DSL project to provide a DSL for the JDBC adapters.

Comment: It works!. Thanks so much. At this moment I am trying to understand the meaning of poller.setAdviceChain(Collections.singletonList (interceptor)). I am getting an error because it is expecting a different type: 
The method setAdviceChain(List<Advice>) in the type PollerMetadata is not applicable for the arguments (List<TransactionInterceptor>)

Comment: Try this `poller.setAdviceChain(Collections.<Advice>singletonList(interceptor));` - expected generic for the method.

Comment: @Artem Bilan: How does one get the `transactionManager` you are referring to in the 2nd snippet?  Thanks.

Comment: The `transactionManager` is a bean reference. In my snippet I use the reference to `@Bean` method. But you can inject it any possible way